# SimpleIoc (MVVMlight) Dependency Inject a List of Interfaces C# Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

Is it possible to use dependency injection in MVVM light on a List of Interfaces?

I've tried having the dependency be `List<IMyInterface> IList<IMyInterface>`. From within the `ViewModelLocator` I have then also tried both with and without the `List<>`. If I do it without `List<>` I get a cache doesn't have a value for List exception, if I do it with, (for List) I get a no preferred constructor exception (as List has multiple constructors, and I can't set the attribute as it is a class inside of .net)

The only possible solution I can think of will limit my testability, which would be to have all the lists as concrete implementations, i.e. I have

```
List<dataType> data = new List<dataType>();
```

Is there a way to IOC a list? or are you supposed to concrete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModelLocator can have static objects that are accessible through it.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    ....
    private static List<IMyInterface> _myInterfaces;
    public static List<IMyInterface> MyInterfaces
    {
        get
        {
            return _myInterfaces;
        }
        set
        {
            // So that it will be readonly. Technically unnecessary, but may be good
            // practice.
            if(_myInterfaces != null) return;
            _myInterfaces = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main app wherever you get your list,

```
ViewModelLocator.MyInterfaces = GetMyInterfaceList();
```

Hope this helps and Happy Coding!

Comment: I don't think that is really correct.. All it is doing is turning my IOC container into a singleton... Just to clarify, I am attempting to make it so that I can Register a List of Interfaces into my IOC container and then dynamically assign what type of class is inside of the List (that implements the interface)

Comment: That's what your IOC is, to an extent. It's static access to 'singleton' ViewModels and controllers, declared via portable interfaces. You do get [some benefits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328263/singleton-vs-servicelocator) for doing this, such as simpler centralized configuration, lifetime management, better testability, lower coupling, separation of concerns, etc.

Comment: I was just trying to use my IOC container to initilize all List's with the interface I specified given a specific implimentation.. From the look of it the main way your supposed to use IoC is 
Interface -> implementation
not
Container<Interface> -> Container<implementation>

Comment: Well, you can have the IOC create the container whenever, you just have to have your app inject the contents at runtime. `ViewModelLocator.MyInterfaces.Add(myExampleObject);`